# How to enable C++17 in CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, c++17

I'm using VS 15.3, which supports integrated CMake 3.8. How can I target C++17 without writing flags for each specific compilers? My current global settings don't work:

```
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# expected behaviour
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++latest")
```

I expected CMake to add "/std:c++lastest" or equivalents when generating VS solution files, but no c++17 flags was found, resulted in compiler error:

```
C1189 #error: class template optional is only available with C++17.
```

Comment: CMake in general does not eliminate need to write flags for each specific compiler.

Comment: With "VS 15.3" do you mean Visual Studio 2017 preview 3? Or do you mean Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (which doesn't support much, if any, C++17)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using `std::optional` features, which can be used if I add `"/std:c++lastest"` flag manually to CMakeLists.

Comment: You need to pass flags to compilers. It is *compilers* that accept C++17, not `cmake`

Comment: it's latest, not laStest

Comment: Just to add a note, the posted approach works great in cmake after 3.10 .

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your approach is the correct one, but it will not work for MSVC on versions of CMake prior to 3.10.

From the [CMake ***3.9*** documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD):

> For compilers that have no notion of a standard level, such as MSVC, this has no effect.

In short, CMake haven't been updated to accommodate for the standard flags added to VC++ 2017.

You have to detect if VC++ 2017 (or later) is used and add the corresponding flags yourself for now.

---

In CMake 3.10 (and later) this have been fixed for newer version of VC++. See [the 3.10 documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD).

Comment: The newer CMake 3.10 (and later) documentation says it works for Visual Studio 2015 update 3 or newer. Only Visual Studio versions before 2015 Update 3 are not supported. The link above actually goes to the latest documentation, which reflects this.

Comment: @Marcus10110 Correct, changed the link to point to the 3.9 documentation. And added note about it being fixed for newer versions. Thanks.

Comment: A (maybe) pedantic comment: to make MSVC behave as a conforming compiler, you also have to use the `/Zc:__cplusplus` flag because otherwise the `__cplusplus` macro is not set to the right value.
A certainly pedantic comment is that I consider this a bug in cmake: when I ask for C++11, C+14, C++17 I want cmake to set *all* flags that are needed to make the compiler conform, and that includes the value of the `__cplusplus` macro.

Answer (score 84):

Modern CMake propose an interface for this purpose `target_compile_features`.
Documentation is here: [Requiring Language Standards](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#requiring-language-standards)

Use it like this:

`target_compile_features(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)`

Comment: @vitaut Can you explain why you rename ${PROJECT_NAME} into ${TARGET_NAME} ?

Comment: Project has a different meaning in CMake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html. `target_compile_features` applies to targets.

Comment: So I changed it for clarity. Feel free to revert.

Comment: I wish accepted answers automatically changed as new language features came out... This is the right answer. the ones above are all very outdated.

Comment: With CMake 3.13 and Visual 2017, I tought this modern command didn't add the `/std:c++17` flag but the `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` did... but it was just a bad keyword `INTERFACE` to `PUBLIC` solved it.

Comment: In CMake, `PUBLIC` (for everyone) = `INTERFACE` (for the other) + `PRIVATE` (for me)

Answer (score 36):

In modern CMake, I've found it best to assign CXX standards at the target level instead of global variable level and use the built in properties (seen here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) to keep it compiler agnostic.

For Example:

```
set_target_properties(FooTarget PROPERTIES
            CXX_STANDARD 17
            CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
            etc..
            )
```

Comment: Per the documentation, CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED is a Boolean. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html

Comment: What does a "modern" CMake mean exactly?

Comment: It seems every cmake feature gets outdated immediately and the Internet is filled with outdated questions and anwsers.

Comment: "Modern CMake" is described in Craig Scott's book.  There have been a number of rethinks along the way which has led to the scripts being more focussed around abstracted targets as opposed to shoehorning compiler flags etc.  Check out his book here: https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/

Answer (score 30):

You can keep that `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` for other compilers, like Clang and GCC. But for Visual Studio, it's useless.

If CMake still doesn't support this, you can do the following for **Visual Studio**:

```
if(MSVC)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++17")
endif(MSVC)
```

**EDIT:** As the question title doesn't mention the compiler, let me add that for **gcc**, **clang** and similar compilers, this is the command to enable C++17:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
```

Comment: [Recent VS changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/what-s-new-for-visual-cpp-in-visual-studio) allow to set standard using `/std:c++14`, `/std:c++17` and `/std:c++latest` flags.

Comment: In my case it's the opposite. I'm using CMake 3.19.1, VS2019 and gcc 7.5.0.
`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` is enough for VS2019, but gcc requilres `target_compile_features(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)`. Even a explicit `add_compile_options("-std=gnu++17")` is not enough.

Answer (score 17):

when using `vs2019`

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Comment: it is working. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Bash command line in CMake flags:

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 \
-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON \
-DCMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS=OFF \
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on my test, the following code will enable VS2019 to select /std:c++latest, otherwise for other platforms it will set the C++ version to C++17. I have tested this with emscripten, raspbian, and windows.

```
if(MSVC)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++latest")
else(MSVC)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
endif(MSVC)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Note that the statement see slightly wrong. According to the [cmake document](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html), the `cxx_std_17` feature means _at least C++17_. So in effect it is similar to the `/std:c++latest` except that it makes sure that you do not compile with an older version (and if a newer version is not available, cmake fails).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `target_compile_options` to set `/std:c++latest` flag for Visual Studio 2019

```
if (MSVC_VERSION GREATER_EQUAL "1900")
    include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
    CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("/std:c++latest" _cpp_latest_flag_supported)
    if (_cpp_latest_flag_supported)
        target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE "/std:c++latest")
    endif()
endif()
```

Replace `${TARGET_NAME}` with the actual target name.

Answer (score 1):

I landed here looking for the right flags to enable standard c++17 with CMAKE.
I don't use MSVS but gcc. So, I hope this help others.

Specifically, I am using CMAKE v3.22.0 and g++ v 11.2.0.

By including the following lines in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, I get the desired option `-std=c++17`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 CACHE STRING "v")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON) #Optional
```

If `set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)` is omitted, `-std=gnu++17` is used instead!
The last line is optional, but it is very useful to check the flags.

Comment: The question was about MSVC, so I don't think this is relevant.