# Enabling C++17 on Android using latest NDK (r18)

Tags: android

From here (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support), it looks like Android NDK r18 provided support for C++17.  The examples though on the page only show how to enable it for the ndk build script approach.  My project is using CMake.

I tried the approach outlined here which is not android specific ([How to enable C++17 in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688522/how-to-enable-c17-in-cmake)) but I was getting compilation errors indicating that my compiler is unable to set the standard to 17.

Is anyone aware on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the "**-std=c++17**" flag to **CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG** and **CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE**, as next:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 -std=c++17 -fexceptions")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -std=c++17 -fexceptions -DNDEBUG")
```

Take into account that the rest of flags are just for the example and will differ depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In your CMakeLists.txt you can specify the C++ standard being used:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Note: this only works in the "first" CMakeLists.txt! If you are including other CMakeLists.txt from yours Android Studio won't use C++17.