# Linker error when using static library with test applications in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, centos7, linker-errors

The project structure of my static library is exactly the same as defined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446495/cmake-project-structure-with-unit-tests) and my CMakeList.txt is exactly the same:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8) 
project (project_name) 

add_subdirectory (src) 
add_subdirectory (test)
```

I want to build the test folder after my static library. I have also added `add_test()` but only **problem** is my test directory doesn't contain unit tests, but actual test application like following code:

```
#include <iostream>
main() {
 /* 
   this code uses static library functions in it. There is not Unit Test defined in it.
*/
}
```

`add_test()` didn't helped me, and I am still getting a `cannot find -ldal` error. `dal` is my static library name, which I have added as `target_link_library` to my test application.

libdal/src/CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(dal)

# Flags Variables
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

# Include Directeries
include_directories(${CPP_KAFKA_INC})
include_directories(${CPP_MYSQL_INC})
include_directories(${CPP_ALTIBASE_INC})
include_directories(${AFN_STATE_INC})
include_directories(${AFN_DAL_INC})
include_directories(${AFN_COMMONS_INC})
include_directories(${AFN_CONFIG_INC})
include_directories(${SQL_ODBC_INC})
# Executable Target(s)
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${AFN_LIB}
        "-lafinit_state"
        "-luuid"
        "-lz"
        "-lpthread"
        ${PQXX_LIB}
        ${PQ_LIB}
        "-lmysqlcppconn"
        ${libmscpp}
        ${kafkacpplib}
        ${rdkafkalib}
        ${rdkafkacpplib}
        afiniti_config $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-lgcov>
        )

# Installation
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"Installing ${PROJECT_NAME} \")")
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

libdal/test/CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(testdal)

# Flags Variables
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17" )

option(DAL_PUSH_TESTER      "enable DAL push tester"    ON)

# Include Directeries
include_directories(${CPP_KAFKA_INC})
include_directories(${AFN_DAL_INC})
include_directories(${CPP_MYSQL_INC})
include_directories(${AFN_STATE_INC})
include_directories(${AFN_CONFIG_INC})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}  main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${AFN_LIB}
        "-lmysqlcppconn"
        "-luuid"
        "-lz"
        ${libmscpp}
        "-ldal"
        ${PQXX_LIB}
        ${PQ_LIB}
        ${kafkacpplib}
        ${rdkafkalib}
        ${rdkafkacpplib}
        "-lafinit_state"
        "-luuid"
        "-lpthread"
        afiniti_config $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-lgcov>
        ${AFN_LICENSE_LIB} "-laf_license_manager"
        )
    # Installation
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"Installing ${PROJECT_NAME} \")")
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin/tests
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)


if (DAL_PUSH_TESTER)
    add_executable(dal_push_tester dal_push_tester.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(dal_push_tester
            ${AFN_LIB}
            "-lmysqlcppconn"
            "-luuid"
            "-lz"
            ${libmscpp}
            "-ldal"
            ${PQXX_LIB}
            ${PQ_LIB}
            ${kafkacpplib}
            ${rdkafkalib}
            ${rdkafkacpplib}
            "-lafinit_state"
            "-luuid"
            "-lpthread"
            afiniti_config $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-lgcov>
            ${AFN_LICENSE_LIB} "-laf_license_manager"
            )
# Installation
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"Installing dal_push_tester  \")")
install(TARGETS dal_push_tester 
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin/tests
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

endif ()
```

Comment: Project structure is somewhat of a user preference thing. I don't think the structure is related to your problems.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you for pointing out, I have added them in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been raised a couple times on the site, but there are some other issues with your CMake file that warrant explanation.

The problem is that the linker doesn't know where to find the `dal` library, because you've only provided `"-ldal"`, without a full path to the library or anything. You can fix this by simply using the CMake library *target* name (`dal`) in `target_link_libraries()` instead, because it was defined earlier in the same CMake invocation.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${AFN_LIB}
        "-lmysqlcppconn"
        "-luuid"
        "-lz"
        ${libmscpp}
        dal              #   <------ Note the change on this line.
        ${PQXX_LIB}
        ${PQ_LIB}
        ${kafkacpplib}
        ${rdkafkalib}
        ${rdkafkacpplib}
        "-lafinit_state"
        "-luuid"
        "-lpthread"
        afiniti_config $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-lgcov>
        ${AFN_LICENSE_LIB} "-laf_license_manager"
        )
```

Furthermore, [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_link_libraries.html) doesn't need the explicit `-l` link flag added; it adds this automatically. Also, you should **always** specify the scoping argument (e.g. `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC`, etc.) for this and other `target_*` calls. Also, also, you have linked `uuid` *twice*, so you can probably remove one of these:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${AFN_LIB}
        mysqlcppconn
        uuid
        z
        ${libmscpp}
        dal
        ${PQXX_LIB}
        ${PQ_LIB}
        ${kafkacpplib}
        ${rdkafkalib}
        ${rdkafkacpplib}
        afinit_state
        pthread
        afiniti_config $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:gcov>
        ${AFN_LICENSE_LIB} af_license_manager
        )
```

In addition, the manual modification of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in this line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
```

is *highly* discouraged. For setting the C++ standard, you should use:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

or one of the other more modern approaches discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45688522/3987854).

I encourage you to browse through some of the content regarding [modern CMake practices](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes, seems like `-ldal` was the culprit