# charconv header not found gcc 12

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++17

I'm running Debian 9 on WSL 2 and I'm trying to compile C++ code that uses the `<charconv>` header. I have the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` in my Cmake file so it's definitely using C++ 17 but when I compile it I get this error message

```
In file included from /mnt/d/blang/frontend/Token.cc:5:0:
/mnt/d/blang/frontend/Token.h:11:20: fatal error: charconv: No such file or directory
 #include <charconv>
```

I build GCC 12 from  source and installed it. When I run `gcc -v` I  get this.

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: you can check the actual command in json compilation database (`compile_commands.json`). Get it by setting `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=on ..`

Comment: Too many unknowns. Try to compile a small c++ program without cmake.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688522/how-to-enable-c17-in-cmake